# Are there ways to get more information about an SmtpClient protocol violation?

Tags: c#, iis-7, smtpclient

I am attempting to send an email using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`.

When the `SendMailAsync` method completes, I get an exception thrown containing the following message text:

> The server committed a protocol violation The server response was:

My problem is, the message does not contain enough information. No server response is shown. When googling around, everything I find shows a string following the `The server response was:` text, but I get only a single blank space.

This exception is elusive, it only occurs on a test server (and a production server), on which I do not have debugger access.

Are there any tricks that I can use to get more information?

Could it be possible that the "server response" is contained in another property in the exception outside of the exception message?

Comment: Can you enable [network tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) and then inspect what went on the wire and what was returned? Although I'm not 100% sure if the SmtpClient will emit much. You might want to check what happens locally first.

Comment: Thanks @rene! I'm giving that a try right now.